# Add action in netzke rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

I wrote this docs at https://github.com/netzke/netzke/wiki/Adding-custom-actions-to-a-component
But I do not understand this.

```
undefined method `js_method'
```

Full component code

```
class Airports < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
include Netzke::Basepack::ActionColumn

js_method :on_show_details, <<-JS
  function(){
    var tmpl = new Ext.Template("<b>{0}</b>: {1}<br/>"), html = "";

    Ext.iterate(this.getSelectionModel().selected.first().data, function(key, value){
      html += tmpl.apply([key.humanize(), value]);
    }, this);

    Ext.Msg.show({
      title: "Details",
      width: 300,
      msg: html
    });
  }
JS

def configure(c)
    super
    c.title = "Airports"
    c.model = "Airport"
    c.columns = [...]
  end
end
```

Why I get this error?

```
undefined method `js_method' for Airports:Class
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Аэропорты</h1>
2: <%= netzke :airports,
3: #  :class_name => "Netzke::Basepack::Grid",
4:   :border => true,
```

Help me please!
I want to add action to context menu.

Comment: What version of Netzke are you on?

Comment: RoR 3.2.21, netzke 0.9.0

Comment: In this docs [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/netzke/netzke-core/Netzke/Core/Actions) this method *`js_method'* missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer.
I have written change.log and I got this thing.

```
js_configure do |c|
  c.on_show = <<-JS
  function(){
    var tmpl = new Ext.Template("<b>{0}</b>: {1}<br/>"), html = "";

    Ext.iterate(this.getSelectionModel().selected.first().data, function(key, value){
      html += tmpl.apply([key.humanize(), value]);
    }, this);

    Ext.Msg.show({
      title: "Details",
      width: 300,
      msg: html
    });
  }
  JS
end
```

It is working now!!!